# Git SSH URL with semver range as npm dependency

Tags: node.js, git, npm, gitlab

While following the [examples from the official npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies):

> ```
> git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/npm.git#v1.0.27
> git+ssh://git@github.com:npm/npm#semver:^5.0
> git+https://isaacs@github.com/npm/npm.git
> git://github.com/npm/npm.git#v1.0.27
> ```

I tried to `npm install` a dependency from a private GitLab repository using a [semver](https://semver.org) range as follows:

```
git+ssh://git@gitlab.example.com:group/project.git#semver:^1.2.3
```

but I received the following error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git checkout semver:^1.2.3
npm ERR! error: pathspec 'semver:^1.2.3' did not match any file(s) known to git.
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /path/to/DATE-debug.log
```

even though specifying a branch or a specific tag worked fine:

```
git+ssh://git@gitlab.example.com:group/project.git#branch_1_2
git+ssh://git@gitlab.example.com:group/project.git#1.2.3
```

**Version info**:

- **os**: ubuntu 18.04
- **node -v**: v10.0.0
- **npm -v**: v5.6.0

Answer (score 2):

**It's a bug**

Replace the colon between the **host** & **path** parts of the URL:

```
git+ssh://git@gitlab.example.com/group/project.git#semver:^1.2.3
         don't use a colon here ^
```

**Info**

You are supposed to be able to use either a colon or a slash according to the [official npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies):

```
<protocol>://[<user>[:<password>]@]<hostname>[:<port>][:][/]<path>[#<commit-ish> | #semver:<semver>]
```

but GitLab [un]helpfully provides you the link with a colon to copy/paste.

As mentioned in this [npm github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17621):

> Seems like this broke as early as 5.1.x. It works when using `npm i -g npm@~5.0.0`

And as mentioned in the referenced [npm github pull request](https://github.com/npm/npm-package-arg/pull/33), the bug has now been fixed but is not yet part of npm as of v5.6.0